# Regex for validation of a street number

Tags: regex

I'm using an online tool to create contests. In order to send prizes, there's a form in there asking for user information (first name, last name, address,... etc).

There's an option to use regular expressions to validate the data entered in this form.

I'm struggling with the regular expression to put for the street number (I'm located in Belgium).

A street number can be the following:

```
1234
1234a
1234a12
```

begins with a number (max 4 digits)
can have letters as well (max 2 char)
Can have numbers after the letter(s) (max3)

I came up with the following expression:

```
^([0-9]{1,4})([A-Za-z]{1,2})?([0-9]{1,3})?$
```

But the problem is that as letters and second part of numbers are optional, it allows to enter numbers with up to 8 digits, which is not optimal.

`1234` (first group)(no letters in the second group) `5678` (third group)

If one of you can tip me on how to achieve the expected result, it would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: If you had chosen an answer, mark it as an answer with a check mark under the digital mark with triangles above and below..... And hm... before acception, ***test*** it....

Comment: A very good question for the first time. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You might use this regex:

`^\d{1,4}([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,2}|)$`

where:

`\d{1,4}` - 1-4 digits

`([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,2}|)` - optional group, which can be

`[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{1,3}` - 1-2 letters + 1-3 digits

or

`[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` - 1-2 letters

or

`empty`

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{0,4}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{0,3}
```

`\d{0,4}`  The first groupe matches a number with 4 digits max

`[a-zA-Z]{0,2}`  The second groupe matches a char with 2 digit in max

`\d{0,3}`  The first groupe matches a number with 3 digits max

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the last two groups together, not allowing the last one to be present, if the second isn't, e.g.

```
^\d{1,4}(?:[a-zA-z]{1,2}\d{0,3})?$
```

or a little less optimized (but showing the approach a bit better)

```
^\d{1,4}(?:[a-zA-z]{1,2}(?:\d{1,3})?)?$
```

As you are using this for a validation I assumed that you don't need the capturing groups and replaced them with non-capturing ones.

You might want to change the first number check to `[1-9]\d{0,3}` to disallow leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answers ! I tried Sebastian's solution :

^\d{1,4}(?:[a-zA-z]{1,2}\d{0,3})?$

And it works like a charm ! I still don't really understand what the ":" stand for, but I'll try to figure it out next time i have to fiddle with Regex !

Have a nice day,

Stan

Comment: Making extra answer is not the correct way to mark an answer. Delete your answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

The first digit cannot be 0.
There shouldn't be other symbols before and after the number.

So:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{0,3})?$
```

The ?: combination means that the () construction does not create a matching substring.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/wEcCk3/5) is the regex with tests for it.